# Print label only once in FusionCharts "plotToolText" for multiseries charts

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

we're using the [multiseries 2d chart from FusionCharts](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes/?chart=msline) for our application. Since the value for the macro `$label` is the same for each series, I'd like to display the information of the hovered series in a tooltip in the following way:

```
<label>
<plotColor1> <seriesName>: <displayValue>
<plotColor2> <seriesName2>: <displayValue2>
...
```

But I only get this:

```
<label1>
<plotColor1> <seriesName>: <displayValue>
<label2>
<plotColor2> <seriesName2>: <displayValue2>
...
```

Currently I'm setting the attribute `plotToolText` to

```
"$label {br} $seriesName: $dataValue"
```

Is there any way to tell FusionCharts to show the label only once per tooltip? 
I would have asked in the FusionCharts forum first, but it seems like you can't create a account (anymore?).

Resources:

- [Demo of my issue](https://jsfiddle.net/xhadon/3qwonuk1/) (hover over any datapoint to see tooltip)
- [Docs about tooltips](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/tool-tips)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The "plotToolText" set will be applicable on all the plots on the chart. So, when crossline is enabled, setting $label in "plotToolText" will display the same label in the tooltip for all the plots residing on that particular label.

To achieve your requirement, alternatively you can use the below work-arounds :

Option 1

Set all the data objects of the first dataset(series) with "toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"

And set all the data objects of the second dataset(series) with
"toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"

Samples for reference : https://jsfiddle.net/5prLxygk

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var visitChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'msline',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '700',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "theme": "fusion",
        "caption": "Number of visitors last week",
        "subCaption": "Bakersfield Central vs Los Angeles Topanga",
        "xAxisName": "Day",
        //"plotToolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
            "label": "Mon"
          },
          {
            "label": "Tue"
          },
          {
            "label": "Wed"
          },
          {
            "vline": "true",
            "lineposition": "0",
            "color": "#62B58F",
            "labelHAlign": "center",
            "labelPosition": "0",
            "label": "National holiday",
            "dashed": "1"
          },
          {
            "label": "Thu"
          },
          {
            "label": "Fri"
          },
          {
            "label": "Sat"
          },
          {
            "label": "Sun"
          }
        ]
      }],
      "dataset": [{
          "seriesname": "Bakersfield Central",
          "data": [{
              "value": "15123",
              "toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "14233",
              "toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "25507",
              "toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "9110",
              "toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "15529",
              "toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "20803",
              "toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "19202",
              "toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seriesname": "Los Angeles Topanga",
          "data": [{
              "value": "13400",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "12800",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "22800",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "12400",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "15800",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "19800",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "21800",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "trendlines": [{
        "line": [{
          "startvalue": "17022",
          "color": "#62B58F",
          "valueOnRight": "1",
          "displayvalue": "Average"
        }]
      }]
    }
  }).render();
});
```

Option 2

Set the chart-level "plotToolText" attribute as below :
"plotToolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"

No need to set "toolText" attribute for the first dataset(series)

And for the data objects of the second dataset(series) set
"toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"

Please  note : "toolText" attribute at data-level, overrites the "plotToolText" attribute at chart-level dataSource.

Sample for reference : https://jsfiddle.net/5prLxygk/1/

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var visitChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'msline',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '700',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "theme": "fusion",
        "caption": "Number of visitors last week",
        "subCaption": "Bakersfield Central vs Los Angeles Topanga",
        "xAxisName": "Day",
        "plotToolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
            "label": "Mon"
          },
          {
            "label": "Tue"
          },
          {
            "label": "Wed"
          },
          {
            "vline": "true",
            "lineposition": "0",
            "color": "#62B58F",
            "labelHAlign": "center",
            "labelPosition": "0",
            "label": "National holiday",
            "dashed": "1"
          },
          {
            "label": "Thu"
          },
          {
            "label": "Fri"
          },
          {
            "label": "Sat"
          },
          {
            "label": "Sun"
          }
        ]
      }],
      "dataset": [{
          "seriesname": "Bakersfield Central",
          "data": [{
              "value": "15123",
              //"toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "14233",
              //"toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "25507",
              //"toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "9110",
              //"toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "15529",
              //"toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "20803",
              //"toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "19202",
              //"toolText": "$label {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seriesname": "Los Angeles Topanga",
          "data": [{
              "value": "13400",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "12800",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "22800",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "12400",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "15800",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "19800",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            },
            {
              "value": "21800",
              "toolText": "$seriesName - $dataValue"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "trendlines": [{
        "line": [{
          "startvalue": "17022",
          "color": "#62B58F",
          "valueOnRight": "1",
          "displayvalue": "Average"
        }]
      }]
    }
  }).render();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just show first series label and hide others.
Please use dataSource.plotToolText attribute instead of tooltext of dataset

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var visitChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'msline',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '700',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "theme": "fusion",
        "caption": "Number of visitors last week",
        "subCaption": "Bakersfield Central vs Los Angeles Topanga",
        "xAxisName": "Day",
        "plotToolText": "<div class='plottooltext-label'>$label</div> {br} $seriesName - $dataValue"
      },
     ...
    }
   })
});
```

Add this style in global css file

```
.fc__tooltip.fusioncharts-div div .plottooltext-label {
    display: none;
}
.fc__tooltip.fusioncharts-div div:first-child .plottooltext-label {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tooltip macros to customize chart labels, data values, display values, etc. as variables, and plain text, to form a completely customized tooltip text. Each chart contains labels, raw values, formatted values, display values, etc., as variables that you use in conjunction with your custom text to form the complete tooltext.

Tooltips can be configured to include supplementary information about the data plotted on a chart. Macros allow you to automate the inclusion of this information, saving the effort of manual customization.

Keep the following pointers in mind when using macros:

Macros are case-insensitive.

A macro which is not applicable will be treated as string.

To use a macro name as text in tooltip use "" before the "$" sign. Example: to show "$value" in tooltip use "$value" in tooltext attribute.

Tooltext can also be configured from corresponding parent nodes (that is, chart, dataset, etc.).

Refer the code below:

```
    {
  "chart": {
    "plotToolText": "Store location: $label <br> Sales (YTD): $dataValue <br> $displayValue"
  }
}
```

To know more about this feature please refer the docs - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/tool-tips#introduction-to-macros

Here is the demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/L935gqf7/

Hope it would be help you out.